# Custom table cell, custom XIB and long press recognizer - can't make them work together

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom cell that has a button on it. I would like to experiment with using a long press instead.

The code that creates the cell looks like this:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
if (!cell) 
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

}
```

(etc)

So I did this:

```
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    if (!cell) 
    {
//      cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellDwellToSpeak" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    }
```

Then I made a copy of the original xib. Deleted the button. Dropped an UILongPressGestureRecognizer on the cell, and created a target by control-dragging form the recognizer to the file's owner:

```
- (IBAction)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;
```

[image]
However, once I start generating cells, I get this error:

```
TypOHD[41541:c07] -[UILongPressGestureRecognizer label]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d0be60
```

What's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got or found an answer to the question as such. What I did learn was that this plan is potentially flawed. Apparently mixing your won gesture recognizers in with the table view is a recipe for disaster, or at least heartbreak.

I my case, I decided to go with a fixed layout that consisted of just the number of items that would be shown anyway. In my app I was really only using a table for historical reasons anyway, and never needed to display more than 7 items.

A workaround and a hack, but it worked for me.